# On histogram equalization

Tags: matlab, image-processing

So I'd like to do it without histeq, but my code seems to get out a rather peculiar, really whited out image, and doesn't seem all too much improved from the original picture. Is there a better way to apply the proper histogram?

```
Cumlative=zeros(256,1);
CumHisty=uint8(zeros(ROWS,COLS));
% First we need to find the probabilities and the frequencies

freq = zeros(256,1);
probab = zeros(256,1);

for i=1:ROWS
    for j=1:COLS
    value=I1(i,j);
    freq(value+1)=freq(value+1)+1;
    probab(value+1)=freq(value+1)/(ROWS*COLS);
    end
end

count=0;
cumprobab=zeros(256,1);
distrib=zeros(256,1);

for i=1:size(probab)
    count=count+freq(i);
    Cumlative(i)=count;
    cumprobab(i)=Cumlative(i)/(ROWS*COLS);
    distrib(i)=round(cumprobab(i)*(ROWS*COLS));
end

for i=1:ROWS
    for j=1:COLS
        CumHisty(i,j)=distrib(I1(i,j)+1);
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do:

```
distrib(i) = round(cumprobab(i)*255);
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a version of your code without the redundant computations, and simplified looping:

```
freq = zeros(256,1);
for i = 1:numel(I1)
   index = I1(i) + 1;
   freq(index) = freq(index)+1;
end

count = 0;
distrib = zeros(256,1);
for i = 1:length(freq)
   count = count + freq(i);
   cumprobab = count/numel(I1);
   distrib(i) = round(cumprobab*255);
end

CumHisty = zeros(size(I1),'uint8');
for i = 1:numel(I1)
   CumHisty(i) = distrib(I1(i)+1);
end
```

I use linear indexing above, it's simpler (one loop instead of 2) and automatically helps you access the pixels in the same order that they are stored in. The way you looped (over rows in the outer loop, and columns in the inner loop) means that you are not accessing pixels in the optimal order, since arrays are stored column-wise ([column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)). Accessing data in the order in which it is stored in memory allows for an optimal cache usage (i.e. is faster).

The above can also be written as:

```
freq = histcounts(I1,0:256);
distrib = round(cumsum(freq)*(255/numel(I1)));
distrib = uint8(distrib);
CumHisty = distrib(I1+1);
```

This is faster than the loop code, but within the same order of magnitude. Recent versions of MATLAB are no longer terribly slow doing loops.

I clocked your code at 40 ms, with simplified loops at 19.5 ms, and without loops at 5.8 ms, using an image of size 1280x1024.

Comment: Yep that was the issue it seems. but are there other Histeq implementations besides the one with histeq and this one?

Comment: @MarorinQ: What you are doing is the standard equalization procedure. There are more involved versions that don't create a completely flat histogram, but take some other things into account to optimize contrast across the image. They are typically used in specialized applications like IR surveillance cameras and so on.

Comment: It is possible to write more efficient code, but I don't think that that is what you were asking about.

Comment: Actually I'm interested in seeing how to make the code more efficient.

Comment: @MarorinQ: I have edited the answer with a faster version of  your code.